# best way to url rewrite a large website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i have a large database and i would like to url rewrite. it is like

```
www.example.com/products.php?id=111&cat=99&f=6&hjk=4545..
```

So I wrote url rewrite for this code to appear as

`www.example.com/men/watches/casio/latest..` like that and its works fine

The problem is that I have a large database and its nearly impossible to write all url rewrites separately.

I thought of generating `.htaacess` file automatically using php. Does that make sense? or whats the best solution for this..?

EDIT: For @ghoti

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/check/([^/]*)/SubjectId/([^/]*)/UniversityId/([^/]*)/CourseId/([^/]*)\.html$ /dsh_course_subjects_topics.php?TopicId=$1&check=$2&SubjectId=$3&UniversityId=$4&CourseId=$5 [L]
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

You need a single rewrite rule to catch the pattern you are looking for and pass it to a php page.  For example:

(note, all of this needs to be on the same line)

```
RewriteRule 
   ^/(men|women)/([a-z]+)/([a-z-])/(latest|newest|expensive|cheapest)$ 
   /products.php?gender=$1&product=$2&brand=$3&filter=$4
```

In that way, you can pass generic request on to PHP where you look at `$_GET` to find out what the dynamic values were, and then pull up the correct items.

If you look at StackOverflow, their URLs look like this:

```
^/questions/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
```

Spend some time looking at ModRewrite documentation as well as Regular Expressions.  Then think how you can positively identify your product (eg, you may need to incorporate an ID in the URL nonetheless).